# Alternatives to code behind animation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a really simple operation - whenever the user hovers his mouse over a rectangle, it should change other rectangle's color. This is how it's done now :

```
<Rectangle Panel.ZIndex="3" Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Rectangle_MouseLeave">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/close.ico"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>

<Rectangle Panel.ZIndex="2" Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="ExitSquare">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="#f9b129"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

---

```
private void Rectangle_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ExitSquare.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(251, 200, 106));
}

private void Rectangle_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ExitSquare.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(249, 177, 41));
}
```

And I'm wondering - are there maybe better options if I'm aiming to use MVVM pattern? Would it be a good idea to try to bind MouseEnter and MouseLeave events and make them operate on a private member of my ViewModel that would be bound to the color of the rectangle or would that just make things unnecessarily complicated?

Comment: You should use styles and xaml animations.

Comment: Are animations and styles supposed to be handled in code behind? It's UI only code, so my assumption would be that it's okay to keep it there but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Wait a minute, setting up answer

Comment: Is this a button you are trying to make?

Comment: Why do you want to react on the MouseOver? What does marking Element B on hovering over Element A mean? That will decide the question if it is a ViewModel or View Side problem.

Comment: It's purely visual - it was meant to serve as an animation.

Comment: If it is purely Visual? A View Side thing. While ideally a View can come out without code behind, ideal cases are not the norm. If you need to write some C# code for the view, do not hesistate. My thought was that you might be going for something like a "next" command with the 2nd element being showin wich will be next (but only on mouse over). That would have been a ViewModel job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You neither need a view model nor any event handlers in code behind.

A Style with a DataTrigger on the other Rectangle's IsMouseOver property is sufficient:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="ImageRect" ...>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/close.ico"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
<Rectangle ...>
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#f9b129"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=ImageRect}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#fbc86A"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>                    
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: What exactly is IsMouseOver binding?

Comment: What you see there in the answer. A Binding to the IsMouseOver property of a UI element.

Comment: It's curious but this doesn't work for me. What's worth mentioning I think is that when I type Binding ... "IsMouseOver" doesn't pop up at all as if it didn't exist.

Comment: Yes, that's how it's supposed to work. It's supposed to change the 'background' of the image. It's basically one rectangle with a transparent image and one with color filling.

Comment: Why shouldn't I be using Style Resource? It makes code much clearer, how does its interpretation change?

Comment: You've set the Style on the wrong Rectangle. The Style with the DataTrigger must be applied to that Rectangle where you want to get the mouse input.

Comment: So what does the ElementName specify? The element where the setter will apply its filling? Because if so, then it's not what I intended. That would replace the image.

Comment: No, I change the Fill of the second Rectangle (your ExitSquare), but bind to the IsMouseOver property of the first Rectangle (the one with the Image fill), where you have MouseEnter and MouseLeave in your question.

Comment: *"the user hovers his mouse over a rectangle, it should change **other** rectangle's color"* is exactly that. The Binding source is the IsMouseOver property of one Rectangle, the (Fill) Setter is applied to the other.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it MVVM, you can bind the two MouseEvents to your `ViewModel`, using `EventToCommand`, which is part of the Blend SDK, through this namespace:

http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity

There's a NuGet package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk/

An example on how to use it:

```
<Rectangle Panel.ZIndex="3" Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/close.ico"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseEnterCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseLeaveCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```

The real question is, why would you want this to be **MVVM**? Is this something you want to unit test? IMO, since this only has to deal with aesthetics, it is perfectly fine to do this in code-behind, as it is not dealing with any data, calculations, state, etc.

Comment: It's not really something I want to unit test. I guess my question should have been "Is it okay to handle UI-mostly code in code-behind and handle data-heavy operations in MVVM or should those two not be mixed".

Comment: @ALazyDoe In most cases you should use xaml for UI work, you should use actual code only if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Alright, this makes things a bit more clear - after your reference to animations and styles I got myself a Resources xaml and now I'm trying to figure out how to handle the animation there to then apply it to my rectangle. Is that the proper way to go around it?

Comment: @ALazyDoe Do you absolutely need it to be a rectangle, not a button?

Comment: Not really. I was going to handle events on that rectangle to make it a button but now I see that I could add a custom button style to make it look like a proper rectangle. I'm just trying to figure out how to animate it properly so that its background would change color whenever hovered on.

Answer (score -1):

This style is set up to be usable for your application.

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Trigger.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                                    </Trigger.Setters>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                    <Trigger.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="Background">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/close.ico"/>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Trigger.Setters>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```